# httpd does not work (-bash: httpd: command not found)

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am on someone else's linux server (shared hosting).  I do not have root access.  I have determined that it's a Redhat 4.1.2-46 running as Centos Release 5.9(Final).

I have the database dump for the site and the .php files from public_html as well.  What I'm TRYING TO DO is locate the httpd.conf file and get the config for that site.

when I type in

```
httpd - v
```

I get -bas: httpd: command not found - even in like the /user/sbin directory - and it's clearly running and there.

Bottom line I can't find the sitedef/conf file for www.thisparticularsite.com - and can't even figure out what version of apache I'm running...

Comment: Assuming by "even in like the /usr/sbin directory" you mean you see the binary in there, what about `/usr/sbin/httpd -v`, or `./httpd -v` when in `/usr/sbin`?

Comment: See if there's a script like `/etc/init.d/httpd` that's normally used to start Apache when the system boots. It should have the path to `httpd` in it.

Answer (score 7):

For Apache 2 try `apache2ctl -v` (or `sudo apache2ctl -v` if root access is available). I'm on a Raspberry Pi 4B running Debian, just for reference.

Answer (score 3):

The `init` files of apache are usually located in `/etc/init.d` the `httpd` path are found in it. However, You can find out where the `httpd.conf` file and `httpd` command directory by doing a `ps aux|grep -i http`. For example:

```
ps aux|grep -i http

510       2594  0.0  0.0  77256  1516 ?        S    Jul02   0:00 **/usr/sbin/httpd-0.0.0.0_80** -k start -f **/etc/httpd/conf/instances/httpd-0.0.0.0_80/httpd.conf**

root      5470  0.0  0.0  77120   872 ?        Ss    2013  22:13 **/usr/sbin/httpd-0.0.0.0_80** -k start -f **/etc/httpd/conf/instances/httpd-0.0.0.0_80/httpd.conf**
```

**Conclusion:**

```
httpd.conf file path: **/etc/httpd/conf/instances/httpd-0.0.0.0_80/httpd.conf**
httpd command directory: **/usr/sbin/httpd-0.0.0.0_80**
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by apache.org, httpd command should not be invoked directly.
[see source](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/programs/httpd.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find loaded modules, earlier the command was `httpd -l`. But it'll give you the same error, `Command 'httpd' not found,`

Nowadays, you can use `apache2 -l` (tested on Apache/2.4.29).